# .Ajax method works on local machine, but not on server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an .Ajax method that calls a method on the page behind (does some logic, then calls a WCF service, then returns an object) that looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'MyPage.aspx/TestMethod',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: "{'Id': '" + Id + "'}",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#randomElement").html(data.d.Foo);
            },
            error: function ((xhr, textStatus, error){
            alert(xhr.statusText);
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(error);

        });
```

And the page behind:

```
  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static MyObject TestMethod(string Id)
        {
            //Logic removed for readability!

            return MyService.GetStuff(Id);

        }
```

This works perfectly fine on my local machine, but fails to work when I deploy to my server.

I have determined that the page behind method does not get called (i.e. the error is in calling TestMethod(), not TestMethod() calling the service).

I have also placed an alert before the .ajax method to show me the path of the page I am on just in case it was doing something funny with the uri on the live server, and it comes back as "/MyPage.aspx" as I would expect.

I also changed the "url:" to the full uri to see if that helped and it didn't.

---

After running fiddler with custom errors off, I get the following error:

> {"Message":"Thread was being aborted.","StackTrace":" at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig,
>   MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)\r\n at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method,
>   Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes
>   methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)\r\n at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)\r\n at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo
>   culture)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object
>   target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object
>   target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.Threading.ThreadAbortException"}

Comment: Should the url be `MyPage.asmx/TestMethod` instead of  `MyPage.aspx/TestMethod`?

Comment: What response are you getting from the ajax request when it fails on the server? Is it returning a 200, 404, 500, something else?

Comment: @JohnPick No, the call is to an aspx web page behind method, not an asmx web service.

Comment: @kendaleiv I have updated the code in the question to show the error handling I have put in place (found from the internet). The messages that show in the 3 alerts are: "Error", "Error" and "Internal Server Error" in that order. Is there a way to get better error details?

Comment: You can examine what the server is returning for the ajax request with Firebug, Chrome Developer Tools, or Fiddler.

Comment: You'll need to run fiddler and see exactly what the server error is.

Comment: The error is a 500 server error, with the only other details fiddler or chrome tools gives me being: "{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}" Is there somewhere else within fiddler that I should be looking for a more detailed exception?

Comment: @Ben Check that your web app is showing the full exception response, and is not just showing a generic error page, and then check the web view inspector tab of the response. It will show the asp.net error page. -- edit -- just saw your edit, you found it! :)

Comment: @Ben I think maybe you are not using the `WebMethod` attribute correctly, every example I've seen applies it to a class in a asmx file, not as aspx file. Take a look at the examples given here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998.aspx

Comment: could it be an IIS issue with the URL? What IIS version are you running on the server?

Comment: Did you copy/deploy your web.config files also?

Comment: asawyer: look up Page Methods (don't have a good url).

Comment: @JayC Ah, I see now. It was long shot guess and I missed. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not valid; you need to use double quotes:

```
data: '{"Id": "' + Id + '"}',
```

Comment: And I don't know why what you have would work on your local machine.  That's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like the it is not posting the right parameters to your method.

I've never used the data option in the .ajax method like you do here before. I use:

```
data: {Id: myId},
```

Where myId is the variable holding the value of the Id you want to pass - without any quotes.

the \r\n is usually something in relation to encoding strings which is not something that should be relevant here, and it seems like you are passing a string data: "{'Id': '" + Id + "'}" instead of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Does your server has a "json"? godaddy, for example, does not offer it